# How to stop VS 2022 Standard Edition from highlighting the code when I select search

Tags: visual-studio-2022

**Background**

Using my newly installed VS 2022, when I search within the text of my code (say using `<Ctrl>+<F3>` followed by `<F3>`), the entire text is background-highlighted in dark-blue, forming a jagged edge of lines.  The jagged edged lines are due to the fact that the lines of my code are not all of same length.  This is especially contrasted against the black background (where I have no code) in "Dark" mode.

The "Blue" mode has the same effect but the contrast of background-highlighted text and background with no text, is not so pronounced.

To end this highlighting I need to escape out of the search mode.

**Question**

How can I stop this background highlighting of the code when I search?

Answer (score 0):

What I needed to do is change the background of the search in "**Find Scope Highlight**"

Select the menu: Tools.(Options...).Environment.(Fonts and Color).(Find Scope Highlight) and change the [Item background] to Black